# How do you understand the Differences in XP Earned graph?

Tags: dota-2

DotaBuff offers a `Differences in XP Earned` graph for matches. [This match](http://www.dotabuff.com/matches/692359846) shows an interesting one with both red and green.

How do you interpret the graph? Is it:

1. From the perspective of the winning team (red = enemy team is earning more XP, green = your team is earning more XP), or
2. Team based (green is Radiant, red is Dire), or
3. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph shows how much ahead in total EXP earned (exp of all heroes of one team added) either side is.

In the given example, at 25 minutes mark, the Dire side is ahead with a total of slightly under 5000 exp, while at 33:20 Radiant are ahead by approximately the same amount

Answer (score 0):

It's Radiant Green vs Dire Red

Comment: -5000 means Dire is earning 5000 more XP per minute than Radiant?

Comment: No, it means that Dire has 5k more XP than Radiant total. Changes are shown minute by minute, but the number is not "per minute".